# How can I change the initial loading image

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I change the initial image when app is loading.  Currently it is set to default.jpg but I don't know where in the project I can change it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for  file called 'Default.png'. In xCode it will likely be in your Resources folder.

If you are supporting anything other than a regular iPhone (so retina or iPad) you will need extra [Launch images](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=840/)

Comment: I had a Default.png in my resource folder I removed it.  I moved a new file there icon1.png.  In info.plist file what do I have to do to show icon1.png at launch?

Comment: You have to specify the value in the plist for UILaunchImageFile if you are using a custom filename.http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

If you don't have that key, simply rename icon1.png to Default.png and it will pick it up automatically

Comment: I have already set Launch image key to the new file.  Itis still loading the old one.

Comment: You might also need to do a clean build and/or delete the app from you device/simulator first.  If you have an old file, it is not deleted, new stuff is just copied over, so any old file that might be a default will be loaded before the new stuff.  This has bitten me a few times.

Comment: How do u delete the app from device/sim?

Comment: Hold down on the app icon (in the simulator/device) until a small red 'x' appears on it and click the 'x' to delete

Answer (score 1):

You change it in the Info.plist.  It is also my understanding that this image must be a .png file, not a .jpg.

Comment: yes png thanks.  I just entered a new image file for "launch image(iPhone)  still loading the old image.  any thought?